# how to redirect repo sync output into a file

Tags: android, shell, repository

I tried "repo sync 2>&1 > log", but can't get anything in log.
The output still gets into the screen directly.

"nohup repo sync" does work, output gets into file "nohup.log".
But it seems any command prefixed with nohup can't work inside crontab.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try with `bash`:

```
 repo sync >log 2>&1
```

Comment: I didn't notice there's an order adjustment for ">log" and "2>&1". It does work now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
repo sync 2>&1 | tee sync.log
```